# C: How to determine sizeof(array) / sizeof(struct) for external array?

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors, sizeof

Defines the type `x` and an array `X` of that type.

x.h:

```
typedef struct _x {int p, q, r;} x;
extern x X[];
```

Separate file to keep the huge honking array `X`.

x.c:

```
#include "x.h"
x X[] = {/* lotsa stuff */};
```

Now I want to use `X`:

main.c:

```
#include "x.h"

int main()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(X)/sizeof(x); i++) /* error here */
        invert(X[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

`main.c` won't compile; the error is:

```
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct x[]’
```

How do I get the size of `X` without hardcoding it?

Comment: if x is a struct you usually have to specify sizeof(struct x)

Comment: no need to use struct if you typedef

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `x.h` add:

```
extern size_t x_count;
```

In `x.c` add:

```
size_t x_count = sizeof(X)/sizeof(x);
```

Then use the variable `x_count` in your loop.

The division has to be done in the compilation unit that contains the array initializer, so it knows the size of the whole array.

Comment: This may solve OP's specific problem, but in general it's deficient since `count` is still not a constant expression and cannot be used in all places you would use `sizeof`. Also, `int` is the wrong type. It should be `size_t`.

Comment: It's as close as you can get with separately compiled modules. The size can only be a constant expression if the array initialization is in the same compilation unit.

Comment: The result of `sizeof` is a constant expression, for the purposes of initializing a global variable. You're completely right about using `size_t` however.

Comment: If you want to avoid having initialized static data you can always make it `size_t x_count(void);`

Comment: @MattMcNabb His point is that the `extern` variable is not a constant expression. But I think that this is not a major failing -- about the only thing you can't do with it is use it in the declaration of another static array.

Comment: @Barmar you need to also change the `int` in your `.h` declaration.

Comment: Thank you, I used this solution with a wrapper `#define XCOUNT x_count` for legacy purposes.

Comment: I don't see a problem with declaring `x_count` as `const size_t`

Answer (score 3):

If it is possible to place a termination indicator at the end of the array, such as:

```
x X[] = {/* lotsa stuff */, NULL};
```

It might be that the number of elements in the array would be irrelevant:

```
#include "x.h"

int main()
   {
   x *ptr = X;

   while(ptr)
      invert(ptr++);

   return 0;
   }
```

If the number of elements in the array is needed,  the above method can be also be used to count the elements.

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution using compound literals:

in `.h`

```
typedef struct _x {int p, q, r} x;

#define LOTSA_STUFF        {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}
#define LOTSA_STUFF_SIZE  sizeof ((x[]) {LOTSA_STUFF})

extern x X[LOTSA_STUFF_SIZE];
```

and in `.c`

```
x X[LOTSA_STUFF_SIZE] = {LOTSA_STUFF};
```

For the definition in `.c`, you can even do better and use a static assert (definition of the `STATIC_ASSERT` is let as an exercise for the reader ;):

```
x X[] = {LOTSA_STUFF};

STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof X != LOTSA_STUFF_SIZE, "oops, sizes are not equal");
```

Comment: What a cool example.  I've never used compound literals and wasn't familiar with the syntax.  There is a really good article on [Dr. Dobb's](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404) for people interested in learning more.

Comment: Oh... and you are missing an 'F' on your `LOTSA_STUF` in the fourth line of the `.h` example.

Comment: This version still does require having the initial data visible in the header, which I think OP was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. But you can provide a way to get the size.

In addition to

```
extern x X[];
```

Add

```
extern size_t xArraySize;
```

or, preferably,

```
extern size_t xArraySize(void);
```

in `x.h`

Define it in `x.c`.

Change your loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i < xArraySize(); i++)
    invert(X[i]);
```

Comment: Why is the function preferable?

Comment: @Rick it allows you to hide the details of how the data is stored.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply include x.h, the compiler has no idea what the real size of X is. Just by looking at x.h, there is no way to guess.
You have to declare X with a size:

```
extern x X[15];
```

Comment: The whole point of using `sizeof(X)/sizeof(x)` is so you don't have to hard-code the number of elements, it's sized automatically from the number of elements in the array initializer.